# How to update xml file using lxml and python?

Tags: python, xml, lxml

```
<example>
    <login>
        <id>1</id>
        <username>kites</username>
        <password>kites</password>
    </login>
</example>
```

How can i update password using lxml?
and now can i add one more record to the same file?

please provide me a sample code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
example = etree.Element("example")
login = etree.SubElement(example, "login")
password = etree.SubElement(login,"password")
password.text = "newPassword"
```

This is a good [tutorial](http://codespeak.net/lxml/tutorial.html)

Comment: after this we need to call etree.write(filepath)
make make effect in xml file

i have found another tutorial which i think is better
http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/pylxml/