# How to change node value using lxml

Tags: python, lxml

I'm trying to modify an xml file using lxml with this code :

```
for elem in doc.xpath('//node_name'):
    elem.text = 'new value'
```

In python interpreter this works (i mean when i access elem.text) , but i want to change the actual xml file that i'm  using. The file remain unchangeable !

Comment: Can toy post the complete code including how you are writing back to file.

Comment: do i have to write into file ?

Comment: with out writing back to file how file will change, or am i missing something.

Comment: i though that lxml library would take care of that !

Comment: Take a look at [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17245310/how-to-update-xml-file-with-lxml) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2108334/how-to-update-xml-file-using-lxml-and-python)

Comment: i'm doing the same thing @MauroBaraldi

Comment: @Bilel_a yes, you'll have to serialize the modified tree again and write it to a file. For example: `xml = etree.tostring(doc, pretty_print=True); outfile.write(xml)`

Comment: what's doc variable ? the filename ?

Comment: @LukasGraf It helped thank you :) put your answer in the comment section so i can validate the answer.